# Accessing MainActivity once BOOT_COMPLETE is received

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have a reminder app that will notify me at a given time when the next reminder from an array of objects it due.

I am trying to make it set the notification again on boot.

I have my boot receiver all set in the Manifest, but how do I access any information from MainActivity once the phone has booted, given that the app hasn't been opened yet?

I was hoping to use this -

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("RegularReminders","onReceive");
        new MainActivity().setNotifications();
    }
}
```

But it returns a null error from within that notification once it tries to run the method in MainActivity, the app crashes as the emulator boots up and I see this in the logcat -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.androidandyuk.regularreminders.BootReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
```

This points to a line -

```
if (reminders.size() >= 0) {
```

I did wonder if I could save the notification message to SharedPrefs and call it back in the receiver, but I got errors of null object reference doing that too.

I tried sending back another broadcast adding extra info, but I guess the receiver set up in MainActivity isn't listening as the app hasn't been run?

I know Google is protecting us from Malware, not letting them do much after book, but is there any way round this so I can set my notification after a reboot?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please at least let me know why so I can learn. I've spent a couple of hours looking for this answer, tried a few different ones I found here on SO, but with no joy, hence me asking.  I feel I've laid out all the info as I should, so please let me know what I have done wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can't access variables from the MainActivity, you can access SharedPreferences and the SQLite Database used in the app, so in this case I made a new array and read the database into it and worked on that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your activity is not created when you receive `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

What  you could do is to start your activity after the boot is completed and pass it arguments to tell it do some work.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("RegularReminders","onReceive");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            //put some args inside the bundle
            //attach the bundle
            i.putExtras(args);
            //start the activity
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't what to start and show your activity. You can use Android [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense for me to look into a service actually.  I've done that when reporting GPS position to a different app, so I guess I can set up a service that monitors the array of objects.  I assume I then use the BootReceiver to start the service up.  In fact, a quick look at the link you gave and maybe I schedule a job?  I've not used them before though, will have to research those. Thanks.